# Problems Running Android (Beginner!)

Tags: android

I'm just currently following the tutorial for creaing android apps (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html). I think ive followed all instructions, but cant seem to be able to run the sample app provided by following their instructions. Here's the responce provided by eclipse:

```
[2012-11-03 14:18:06 - My First App] ------------------------------
[2012-11-03 14:18:06 - My First App] Android Launch!
[2012-11-03 14:18:06 - My First App] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-03 14:18:06 - My First App] Performing com.example.my.first.app.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-11-03 14:18:06 - My First App] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'TestDevice1'
[2012-11-03 14:18:06 - My First App] Uploading My First App.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-11-03 14:18:07 - My First App] Installing My First App.apk...
[2012-11-03 14:20:22 - My First App] Failed to install My First App.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-11-03 14:20:22 - My First App] (null)
[2012-11-03 14:20:22 - My First App] Launch canceled!
[2012-11-03 14:23:00 - My First App] ------------------------------
[2012-11-03 14:23:00 - My First App] Android Launch!
[2012-11-03 14:23:00 - My First App] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-03 14:23:00 - My First App] Performing com.example.my.first.app.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-11-03 14:23:00 - My First App] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 
'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'TestDevice1'
[2012-11-03 14:23:00 - My First App] Uploading My First App.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-11-03 14:23:01 - My First App] Installing My First App.apk...
[2012-11-03 14:25:24 - My First App] Failed to install My First App.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-11-03 14:25:24 - My First App] (null)
[2012-11-03 14:25:25 - My First App] Launch canceled!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You will likely see your error, in another the Android log (called logcat).  There is a logcat view in eclipse (or you can see the log by typing:  'adb logcat' on the command line).  I would bet your error is clear in this log (post the output in your question if you can - and we will help).  Bottom line, not enough info in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse?.

Were you ever able to run the program before?

If you could then restart your emulator/computer(try restarting your emulator first).
I used to get this error once in a blue moon and only restarting the computer used to solve it.

I still haven't figured out why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by restarting the Eclipse and relaunching the Emulator !

Try it out once.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Project's properties: Properties/Android/Project Build Target to Android 4.4.2 API 19 and the app should work.